# capture html within a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

capture the content of a component child, this component and this in turn calls another, in this second component there is an html, in this second component in the code javascripot capture this component to use it

> first component, has as component child -- field --

```html
<template>
    <div id="login">
       <field type="select" name="lang">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>zero</option>
        </field>
    </div>
</template>
```

> second component, is field

```
<template>
    <div class="field input">
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <div v-html="htmlfield"> </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['type'],
    computed : {
            htmlfield : function(){
              switch (this.type) {
                    case 'select':
                        return `<select ${attr}>**__here__**</select>`; break;
              }
            },
    },
}
</script>
```

**__here__** I want to put the options indicated in the first component

I would like to be able to capture with javascript the html of a component

Comment: The best way I know of sharing content between components is to use `props`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a universal `<field>` that you can pass the type of input you want.

Can I suggest a different approach?

First component

```
<template>
    <div id="login">
      <field type="select" :options="options" name="lang"></field>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      options: [
        { label: 'one', value: 'value1' },
        { label: 'zero', value: 'value2' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Second component:

```
<template>
      <div class="field input">
        <label>{{ label }}</label>

        <select v-if="type === 'select'">
          <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value" :key="option.value">{{ option.label }}</option>
        </select>

        <input v-if="type === 'text'" type="text">
        <input v-if="type === 'number'" type="number">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['label', 'type', 'options']
}
</script>
```

Here, instead of writing the `<option>` elements in the parent template, we create option objects in an array called `options` and pass it to `<field>` as a prop, then we can render the `<option>` elements in the child IF the `'type' === 'select'`.